# ActionLink throws HTTP 404.0 – Not Found error // ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, actionlink

I've got an issue with passing name of clicked ActionLink to controller and using it. 404 error appears when click. 
This is part of my view called Scan.cshtml

```
<tbody >
                @foreach (string item in ViewBag.files)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class=" row col-md-12 "> @Html.ActionLink(item, "Download", "Scan", new { id = item }, new { style = "color: #424242" })</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

This is the part from ScanController where am I trying to operate with sent data. I think it doesn't get to the controller logic at all and throws error sooner.

```
    public ActionResult Download(string id)
    {
        // controller logic for downloading file
        var ftpko = new MyProject.Helpers.ftp(@path, name, passwd);
        ftpko.download(id, "~/Dotazniky/dotaznik.jpg"); 

        return View();
    }
```

Let's say item = "car.jpg", error says requested path - http://localhost:53593/Scan/Download/car.jpg not found.

This is the RouteConfig file:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you ending your url name with `.jpg`, and the request is going to search for a Content file, not to execute an Action.

There are ways to disable this, but i think the most easy solution is to send `name` and `extension` in separate parameters.

Action become:

```
public ActionResult Download(string name, string ext)
{ 
     string id = name + "." + ext;
```

Add a new route

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "TwoParameters",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{ext}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
    );
```

Modify the `ActionLink`

```
@{ var params = item.Split('.'); }
@Html.ActionLink(item, "Download", "Scan", new { name = params[0], ext = params[1] }, new { style = "color: #424242" })
```

**Notes:** There are other ways (others than `.Split('.')`) to take extension and the filename.

Comment: Thank you for superfast answer. You are right. It trully was the problem. I hope this will help others with the same problem in the future.